# '05 Peugeot 307: Oil in the Coolant

Tags: oil, coolant, repair, peugeot, gasket

I have a 2005 Peugeot 307 hatchback.

*Back in May,* the head gasket blew so I had it replaced. When the head gasket blew, oil was leaking out and the coolant became very gungy. This gunge was cleared out, but not completely.

*About 2 weeks ago,* I checked the coolant and oil. The coolant was fine, but I topped the oil up.

*Now,* I just checked both again.  The oil is fine, but the coolant is very gungy and oily, with a dark marshmallowey colour.

I have done about 3000 miles since the head gasket was replace. **There is no oil leaking out of the car and the oil level seems the same as it was 2 weeks ago.**

I'm not sure whether this is relevant, but since the head gasket was replaced I have gone from doing long distance journeys to stop-start city centre journeys.

**Could anyone give me some indication of what the cause is or whether there is anything else I should check?**

Comment: Do you have an automatic transmission with the trans cooler built into the radiator?

Comment: The most obvious answer is that the head gasket was installed badly.  I know that's not the answer you want to hear.  Who installed it?